# Unexepected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, sql

Unexecpected T_VARIABLE in SQL Query on Line 5
How to fix this?

```
<?php
    include "system.php";
    $usersystem = $_SESSION['username'];
    $passw = $_SESSION['password'];
    $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "$usersystem" AND password = "$passw";
    $autoexec= $mysqli->query($query);
    $earnings = $autoexec['earnings'];
    $completed = $autoexec['completed'];
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] !=1){
        header ('Location: index.php);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please consider using **prepared queries** instead, in which case none of this would ever happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax highlighter makes your issue obvious: quotes. You need to use single quotes for your strings in your query:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usersystem' AND password = '$passw'";
```

Comment: so the varibles won't evaluate to variables. great advice

Comment: @Alexander The variables will still evaluate to variables. The outermost quote is double-quote

Comment: @Alexander Inside a double quotes string the variables *are* interpolated

Comment: allright, I confused it with perl

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP syntax:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "$usersystem" AND pas
                                              ^--         ^---
```

You cannot use the same type of quotes that you've used to delimit the string. Try

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = \"$usersystem\" AND pas
                                              ^---         ^--- note the escapes
```

And since this is a simple typo-type problem, voting to close the question...

Comment: why use qoutes at all?

Comment: `... username=foo`... do you think the OP's got a field name `foo` in their table?

Comment: I don't uderstand you. Anyway, I asked what's the problem with `username = $usersystem` ?

Comment: Exactly that. With no quotes around the variable in the query string, the variable's contents will be interpreted as a field name. Say you're using the OP's system. ... `SELECT ... WHERE username=Alexander`... there will NOT be an `Alexander` field in the OP's table to compare username again. But `username='Alexander'` will compare the STRING alexander against the username field in the table.

Comment: @Alexander I mean no offense by this, but you should really brush up on your PHP skills if you want to start criticizing others. You've incorrectly commented on both of these answers.

Comment: @MarcB well, concatenation is faster, anyway

Comment: @Alexander No it's not http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

Comment: @MikeB [less emotions, more tests](http://www.phpbench.com/)

Comment: @Alexander A benchmark run on every page load vs a core PHP developer explaining with op codes. I'll take the latter.

Comment: @MikeB and I don't see any logic in this